# Cannot get a Cloud Function to fetch data from Google Cloud IoT Pub/Sub topic and store it in a Firestore Database

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a microcontroller sending data to a topic in Google Cloud Pub/Sub service, and I'm receiving the data successfully:
[image: messages]

I created a Cloud function in Firebase with the purpouse of store the received data in a Database every time a message arrives in a particular topic named "sensors".

This is my index.js file:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
  PubSub = require(`@google-cloud/pubsub`),
  admin = require("firebase-admin");

const app = admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = app.firestore();
var num = 0;

firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

const auth = app.auth();

exports.deviceState = functions.pubsub.topic('sensors').onPublish(async (message) => {
    const deviceId = message.attributes.deviceId;
    const deviceRef = firestore.doc(`device-configs/${deviceId}`);
    try {
      await deviceRef.update({ 'state': message.json, 'online': true, 'timestamp' : admin.firestore.Timestamp.now() });
      console.log(`State updated for ${deviceId}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`${deviceId} not yet registered to a user`, error);
    }
});
```

It's my understanding that this Cloud Function should create and populate a Database, but there's no database in my Firebase project, here are the logs from Firebase:

```
9:18:51.107 PM
deviceState
Function execution started
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52)
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
aquast1-dev not yet registered to a user Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/project-id/databases/(default)/documents/device-configs/aquast1-dev
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
Caused by: Error
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at WriteBatch.commit (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:417:23)
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at DocumentReference.update (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:393:14)
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at /workspace/index.js:17:23
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:23)
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:199:28
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
code: 5,
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
details: 'No document to update: projects/project-id/databases/(default)/documents/device-configs/aquast1-dev',
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
9:18:51.148 PM
deviceState
}
9:18:51.149 PM
deviceState
Function execution took 43 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
Logs are subject to Cloud Logging's
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here? What am I missing?

Comment: "but there's no database in my Firebase project," => What do you exactly mean? Have you initialized the Firestore DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you are trying to update a document that doesn't exists, try to use "set" instead of "update", you can always pass { merge: true } as an option then it will behave like an update

```
await deviceRef.set({ 
    'state': message.json, 
    'online': true, 
    'timestamp' : admin.firestore.Timestamp.now() 
}, { merge: true });
```

Comment: @Gabriel Robledo Ahumada For more information, you can look at these public doc that explains all about [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) and [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)in the Firestore.